# VueJS + Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vuejs2

basically what i want to approach is getting the width of an element when i use the resizable() of jquery ui and save it in my vue data.

```
<div class="draggable"></div> 
$(".draggable").draggable().resizable();
```

When i now drag the element with the handler i want to get the actual width in my vue js component script... Can i somehow get it on each tick with a ref ?

So whenever my div looks like this in a rendered version:

```
<div style="width: 100px;" class="draggable" />
```

I want to access that width in Vue somehow.

A code sample would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use VueJS's $data API :

HTML

```
<div id="my-app">
  My width is: {{ mywidth }}
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>
```

And make Jquery send your width to vuejs:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-app',
    data: {
      mywidth: 100,
    }
});
```

And:

```
$(".draggable").draggable().resizable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
     var width = ui.size.width;
     app.$data.mywidth = width;
}
});
```

You can replace `stop(event, ui)` by `resize` so you'll be able to track width while resizing and not getting with after 'resizing is done'

Example on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Fcmam5/pen/jmPNjV)

Read more:

- [JqueryUI Resizable {stop( event, ui )}](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-stop)
- [Vuejs vm.$data API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data)